# Fine tune BERT model to predict aspect-based sentiment analysis model

Tags: nlp, sentiment-analysis, bert-language-model

I'm new to transformers for NLP. I'm building an aspect-based sentiment analysis model. which is training a model to predict aspects of product features in the customer reviews on my website and extract the sentiment of each aspect. This is a sample of training data I prepared manually. The problem I encounter is that I can find lots of documents for text classification problems with transformers but not for this scenario. I have an intermediate level of knowledge in NLP and LSTM. I just want to know if can I use BERT to build these kinds of models.

sample instance:

{
"text": "Lovely color on brown skin lasting power decent for a gloss minimal plumping effect .",
"aspects": [
{
"aspect_term": "Color",
"sentiment": "positive",
"start": 7,
"end": 13
},
{
"aspect_term": "Durability",
"sentiment": "positive",
"start": 27,
"end": 40
},
{
"aspect_term": "Texture",
"sentiment": "positive",
"start": 68,
"end": 76
}
]
}

Thank You!

I can not build the transformer model.